# Can funds from a UTMA account be used to buy a phone for the minor?

Tags: united-states, minor

Can the custodian of a Uniform Transfers to Minors Act (UTMA) account withdraw funds and use them to buy a phone for a minor at the minor's request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Investopia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/u/utma.asp) tells me that "each state has the option to adopt or amend the UTMA for its residents."

In [alaska](/questions/tagged/alaska), for example, the answer is **YES**, under [AK Stat § 13.46.130 (2014)](https://law.justia.com/codes/alaska/2014/title-13/chapter-13.46/section-13.46.130/)
as...

> (a) **A custodian may deliver or pay to the minor or expend for the minor's benefit as much of the custodial property as the custodian considers advisable for the use and benefit of the minor**, without court order and without regard to
>
> - (1) the duty or ability of the custodian personally or of another person to support the minor; or
> - (2) other income or property of the minor that may be applicable or available for that purpose.
>
> (b) On petition of an interested person or the minor if the minor has attained the age of 14 years, the court may order the custodian to deliver or pay to the minor or expend for the minor's benefit as much of the custodial property as the court considers advisable for the use and benefit of the minor.
>
> (c) A delivery, payment, or expenditure under this section is in addition to, not in substitution for, and does not affect an obligation of a person to support the minor.